# How to insert a relation between two tables, where a determined data set is related to a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, dataset, mysql-workbench

Well, for a project, I need to relate a determined data set to a primary key and give this relation a 'strength' (any numerical value).

I did some searchs, and the only answer I've found is creating new tables for each new relation. However, if I had 100 relations with differents data sets, there would be 100 tables, and this could be very dangerous to the data base operation.

I want to find a way to relate that set of data with a primary key and give a number to that specific relation, where other relations can have other sets of tags and their values.

This picture shows an example. Certain data sets can have different strength values when related to the same primary key

[image]

Comment: This is rather incomprehensible. What do you want to store? how is the data related? And what result do you need when you retrieve it? Include all of you question editing the question here IN TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about designing the database as below:

**Table 1:**

```
    TagID     Tag     Strength  
    =====     =====   ========  
    1         Feather 0  
    2         Paws    100  
    3         Beak    150  
    4         Wings   150
```

**Table 2:**

```
    SpeciesID     Species     TagID (Relation)  
    =========     =======     =====  
    B1            Bird        4        
    B1            Bird        1  
    B1            Bird        3

    B2            Bird        2  
    B2            Bird        1   
    B2            Bird        3   
    B2            Bird        4 

    B3            Bird        2   
    B3            Bird        1
```